# Error with babel-macros when create npm package

Tags: reactjs, installation, babeljs

I've a problem with babel-plugin-macros, currently I created a component package with twin.macro, the compiler shows a success message, and the npm publish command too. But, if I install the library and use on my project shows the next error:

> MacroError: The macro you imported from "undefined" is being executed
> outside the context of compilation with babel-plugin-macros. This
> indicates that you don't have the babel plugin "babel-plugin-macros"
> configured correctly. Please see the documentation for how to
> configure babel-plugin-macros properly:
> https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-macros/blob/master/other/docs/user.md

The libraries babel-macros-plugin and tailwind already been setup in the project

Answer (score 0):

I go this same error because we changed some files to .tsx and forgot to update the babel extensions.